# Merge Cells option is not available for columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, merge, ssrs-2008

I have created one SSRS report. While trying to merge 2 cells on the top Right most corner the option seems to be unavailable. Why it happened so? Is there any idea to make it available.Here is my snapshot of table and grouping. The highlighted columns need to merged.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're attempting to merge a cell that's within a column grouping to a cell that's outside that group (I.E. the top left one)? That won't work - the cell inside the group can potentially generate multiple columns in the rendered table, so Report Builder won't allow you to merge it with another cell that isn't within the same group.

You could perhaps simply remove/hide that top row and instead place a text box above the table containing your expression? You'll need to consider the size of it carefully to make sure it doesn't look out of place though.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the group column but keep the group. Insert a column within the group, use the column as your Project Name, then you can merge the cell.